# Proof: Inverse Image of strictly increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let the real function $f$ be strictly increasing.

I'm having some real problems show that for any $b$ in the real numbers, $f^{-1}(b)$ is either empty of consists of a single element, and that $f$ is therefore an injection.

I am assuming that we need to break it into cases where:

$b$ is in $\mathrm{Ran}(f)$ and when $b$ is not in $\mathrm{Ran}(f)$.

Can someone provide a proof?

Also on a side note: If $f$ is also a bijection, would the inverse of $f$ also be strictly increasing?

Answer (score 1):

If there are two real numbers $x<y$ in $f^{-1}(b)$, then we have $x<y$ but $f(x)=b=f(y)$, which contradicts the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing. Therefore $f^{-1}(b)$ can contain at most one element.

For your second question, suppose that $f$ is a bijection but that the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is not strictly increasing. Then there are real numbers $x<y$ such that $f^{-1}(x)\geq f^{-1}(y)$. But since $f$ is increasing, this implies that
$$ x=f(f^{-1}(x))\geq f(f^{-1}(y))=y $$
which is a contradiction. Therefore $f^{-1}$ is also strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

There can be issues of how to write a proof rigorous enough to be acceptable. This comes by observation and practice.

The other issue is understanding the problem in simple words beyond the symbols. I will focus on this. An increasing function can be said in words this way: higher the input given, higher the output it yields.

What is the meaning of inverse image being  not a  singleton? Either it is empty or has more than one element.  In the non-empty case  same output is the result for two different inputs (or more). Among those multiple inputs one should be higher than the other. But by definition higher input cannot yield the same output as the lower input.  So a contradiction. So inverse image has to be singleton if nonempty.

Inverse function reverses the role of input and output. So can argue using words that it will be increasing if the original functions is.